# For loop that splits strings by n characters

Tags: python, for-loop, slice

I found this code that does exactly what I want, it splits a string by n characters. But can somebody explain to me what this code looks like in a long-form for loop?

```
n = 3
chunks = [str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str), n)]
print(chunks)
```

I have a hard time understanding the logic of this code in it's current format. If I were to re-write it, it would look something along the lines of the code below, but can't replicate the results.

```
for i in range(0, len(str), n):
    chunks = ''
    string = str[i*n::n]
    chunks = chunks+string
```

[Source of code](https://pythonexamples.org/python-split-string-into-specific-length-chunks/)

Comment: You're re-creating chunks in every loop iteration. You probably want to create chunks outside of the loop, and use some additive operation to concatenate.

Comment: That is a list comprehension. The problem with your attempt at reproducing it is that your reset chunks to be `''` *inside* the loop.

Comment: Also, `chunks` is a *list* to append to, not a string to concatenate with another string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension that looks like

```
result = [value for element in iterable]
```

is exactly equivalent to the following code:

```
result = []
for element in iterable:
    result.append(value)
```

Consequently your code would be simply

```
chunks = []
for i in range(0, len(str), n):
    chunks.append(str[i:i+n])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 3
inputString = "this is my string"
chunks = []
for i in range(0, len(inputString), n):
    myString = inputString[i:i+n]
    chunks.append(myString)
print(chunks)
```

Chunks is an array! Not a string. Hope its helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
chunks = []
for i in range(0, len(str), n):
    string = str[i:i+n]
    chunks.append(string)
```

Comment: I did not test - I was assuming OP had the right contents in the array posted in the original code, and just wanted to re-write the loop.

Comment: The original list comprehension is [i:i+n]. You shoudl stick to that

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize they were different.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a simple list comprehension is as follows:

```
result = [ <some calculation on variable(s)> for <variable(s)> in <iterator> ]
```

In a for loop this translates to:

```
result = []
for <variable(s)> in <iterator>:
    result.append(<some calculation on variable(s)>)
```

In your case `str[i:i+n]` is the *some calculations on variable i*, `i` is *the variable* and `range(0, len(str), n)` is the *iterator*

Each entry produced by the iterator `range(0, len(str), n)` is placed in variable `i` which is then processed by `str[i:i+n]` as a new item for the resulting list.

The `range()` function produces values from a starting point `0` up to (but not including) an ending point `len(str)` striding by a step value `n`.

The [] on the right of `str` *(very bad name for a variable btw as it is the name of the string type)* picks out a range of characters defined the same way as for the range() function but separated by colons instead of commas.